# Transfer Data using IF THEN statements from sheet 1 to 2

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I would like to transfer data from sheet1 to sheet2 as indicated in the below pictures. I thought it best to use an `if` statement. For example, `if` a cell in the search range equals "RES", `then` place entire column containing "RES" on sheet2 starting at row 3 of the first empty column. `ElseIF` the next cell in the search range has a "B" in it, then place that entire column containing the cell with a "B" in it two columns from the "RES" column on sheet2, but place any other column with a "B" in it after the last column with a "B" in it on sheet2.

The code below will place the "RES" column starting at "A1" on sheet2 (I cannot figure out how to place it starting at row three). It will not transfer any columns with "B" in the header. It should be noted that the letter "B" need not always be in the first position of the string. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Pic1]

[image]

Code:

```
Sub TransferValues()

'If statement

Dim SrchRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim lc As Long
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set SrchRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lc & "")

For Each cell In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "RES") > 0 Then 'works
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(3, 0).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value

    ElseIf InStr(1, cell.Value, "A", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'does not work
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
    End If
Next cell
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I **highly** recommend changing `cell as Range` to something other than `cell`.  That's because `Cell` has its own, built in meaning for VBA, and using `cell` as a variable could cause confusion for you and/or VBA. For exactly what you're doing, I just use `cel as Range` instead (then it'd be `For Each cel in SrchRng`).

Comment: Unfortunately, these changes (changing A1 to A3) did not correct the issue. The "RES" column is still starts at A1 and the "B" columns are not transferred.

Comment: The issue was that I didn't specify my search range correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some notes and adjustments in the code.

1. You set the search range to A1:A4 not A1:D1
2. You are searching for A in your code not B
3. The offset you use will put any columns with B in sheet2 column C so I added a counter for the row.

   ```
   Sub TransferValues()
   'Added counter
   Dim pasteColOffset As Long

   pasteColOffset = 0
   'If statement

   Dim SrchRng As Range, cell As Range
   Dim lc As Long
   lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   'This will set the seach range to A1:A4
   'Set SrchRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lc & "")

   Set SrchRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(1, lc)

   For Each cell In SrchRng
       If InStr(1, cell.Value, "RES") > 0 Then 'works
           Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(3, 0).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
           pasteColOffset = pasteColOffset + 2
   'This is looking for String "A" not String "B"
   'ElseIf InStr(1, cell.Value, "A", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'does not work

       ElseIf InStr(1, cell.Value, "B", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

   'This will always place the data in column 3 maybe add a counter
   'Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value

           Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Offset(0, pasteColOffset).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
           pasteColOffset = pasteColOffset + 1
       End If
   Next cell
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
   ```

I didn't tackle the pasting in row 3 since I'm out of time but its happening because you are using the entirecolumn property.  You can't use entire column if you don't want to paste the entire column you will need to get the actual ranges (highly preferable) or insert cells above after pasting.

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I missed setting the search range correctly. Thanks. I haven't seen `Resize` before. I'll have to look it up. I will take care of inserting rows at the end. The only part I don't quite get is `pasteColOffset = pasteColOffset + 2`. I ran the code without it and the "RES" column didn't appear on sheet2.

Comment: I'm just using pasteColOffset to determine which column to paste in (offsetting from Column A)  if you leave out the ...+2 pasteColOffset remains 0 so the first column with B in it would overwrite it.  The way you had it previously would always paste in column C so I needed to add the variable.  The plus 2 gives the gap after the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Change `A1` to `A3`.
**From**

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(3, 0).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
```

**To**

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(3, 0).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
```

Similarly **from**

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
```

**To**

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Value = cell.EntireColumn.Value
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these changes did not correct the issue. The "RES" column is still starts at A1 and the "B" columns are not transferred.

Comment: The issue was that I didn't specify my search range correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TransferValues()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim cRange As Range, vRange As Range
Dim xCol As Integer

Dim lc As Long
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
Set SrchRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(1, lc)



For Each cell In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "RES") > 0 Then
        Set cRange = Range(cell, cell.End(xlDown))
        Set vRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(2, 0).Resize(cRange.Rows.Count, 1)
        vRange.Value = cRange.Value
    ElseIf InStr(1, cell.Value, "B", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set cRange = Range(cell, cell.End(xlDown))
        xCol = 1
        Do While Len(Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(2, xCol)) > 0
            xCol = xCol + 1
        Loop
        Set vRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(2, xCol).Resize(cRange.Rows.Count, 1)
        vRange.Value = cRange.Value
    End If

    Set cRange = Nothing
    Set vRange = Nothing

Next cell
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain what the `Do While Loop` is doing?

Comment: len() is the length of the contents of the cell.  So it is moving over one cell on a loop until the length of the contents is 0.  It just keeps adding 1 to xCol until it gets to an empty column.

Comment: Thanks again! Very clever.